# How do I use $ sign or HTML &#36; symbol with this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I use `$` or HTML `&#36;` ("`$`") symbol with this JavaScript?

```
var cash =document.getElementById('cash').value;    
var total =document.getElementById('total').value;  

document.getElementById('prepaid').value=  parseFloat(getObj("cash").value) - parseFloat(getObj("total").value);
```

Comment: What do you mean, "use $ sign"?  Use it how?

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
document.getElementById('prepaid').value =
  '$' + (parseFloat(getObj("cash").value) - parseFloat(getObj("total").value));
```

(Note the parentheses around the subtraction; without them, `'$' + a - b` is interpreted as `('$' + a) - b`, which will not give the results you want.)

But be aware that, because floating-point values cannot be represented exactly, this can give strange-looking results; you might end up with a string like `$3.00000000001` or `$2.999999998`, which is probably not what your users will expect!